# HttpClient request to Axios

Tags: angular, axios, frontend, httpclient

Im new working with frontends and backends, I needed to make some authentication request using an API that is not mine, I tought that It will be possible using just the Angular frontend but I happens that every request I made I was getting a CORS POLICY error, so I made a little more research and I found a way to avoid this, "Making a Backend" and make the request to the API using axios.

**So tis is the method that I call from the Angular frontend**

```
CallBitlyServiceGetAccessToken() {
   const res = this._bitlyApiService.GetAccessToken(this.clientId, this.clientSecret).then(res => 
   console.log(res));
  }
```

**this is the method in the other class.**

```
  const endpoint = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'aplication/json',
  }
});

  GetAccessToken(ClientId: string, ClientSecret: string) {
    return endpoint.post('/access_token', {ClientId, ClientSecret}).then(res => {
      console.log('hola' + res);
      return res;
    });
  }
```

**This is the method in the backend.**

```
app.post('/access_token', function(req, res) {
    const basicAuth = new Buffer(`${req.body.ClientId}:${req.body.ClientSecret}`);
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + basicAuth.toString('base64'),
        },
        url: `https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token`,
    };
    axios(options).then(token => {
        console.log(token.data);
        res.send(token.data);
    });
});
```

the problem is that the infromation I print in the server is correct but that data is not being sent back to the frontend so I can work with it.

Comment: 1st thing is that it doesn't make sense to do authentication checks with a 3rd API unless it is something similar to OAuth. 2nd thing is that to fix the CORS error, you need to enable it in your browser as well as the server.

Comment: It seems that the issue was because I was using express.json and it was not working with it, I rather used body-parser and its working now!